# why this event (onclick) do not fire?

Tags: gwt

UI:

```
  <div class="scroll" ui:field="mainContainer">
                <ul ui:field="liContainer">
                </ul>
    </div>
```

code :

```
LIElement li = Document.get().createLIElement();
AnchorElement a = Document.get().createAnchorElement();
a.setAttribute("href", "#");
li.appendChild(a);
Image img = new Image(fsd.getImgUrl());
img.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.alert("Hello, again");
    }
});
SpanElement span = Document.get().createSpanElement();
span.setInnerText(fsd.getName());
a.appendChild(img.getElement());
a.appendChild(span);
liContainer.appendChild(li);
```

Note:

```
@UiField
UListElement liContainer;
```

Comment: You need to do an effort when asking a question if you want someone to be interested in! I think you misunderstand the politic of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The `Image` must be added to a parent `Widget`.  By attaching the image's element directly to the DOM, you wind up bypassing GWT`s event dispatch system.